# Diagnostic Trouble Codes can not be find using api's

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am Currently working on application which has facility to finding DTC(Diagnostic Trouble Codes) for adding this facility I am currently use
https://github.com/jeffmcfadden/CarDash for my references but using this I got Only rpm using mode 01. I need DTC (For ex. P0002) that can not find from that. can any one help me out for that.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs